# Find chromatic polynomial of a graph $K_{n,m}$

Tags: combinatorics

> Find chromatic polynomial of a graph $K_{n,m}$

**My solution:**

 Let's define the lower and upper factorials by examples:

- lower factorial: $$t^{\underline{3}}=t(t-1)(t-2)$$
- upper factorial: $$t^{\overline{3}}=t(t+1)(t+2)$$

Knowing this my polynomial is:

$$W(t)=(t-{\underline{\text{min}(n,m)}})^2 (t-\text{min}(a,b))^{|n-m|}$$
Can you check my reasoning?

Comment: I don't see any reasoning (and what are $a$ and $b$? ;) Anyway, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The chromatic polynomial $\chi_G(t)$ of a graph $G=(V,E)$ can always be [written](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial#Colorings_using_all_colors) as $$\chi_G(t)=\sum_k a_k(t)_k,\qquad(t)_k=t(t-1)\ldots(t-k+1),$$ where $a_k$ is the number of partitions of $V$ into $k$ nonempty [independent sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)).
2. Generalizing the construction of $K_{n,m}$, the [graph join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_operations#Binary_operations) of two graphs is the graph obtained by joining (with an edge) each vertex of the first graph with each vertex of the second graph. Formally, the graph join of $G_1=(V_1,E_1)$ and $G_2=(V_2,E_2)$, $V_1\cap V_2=\emptyset$, is the graph $G_1\diamond G_2=(V,E)$ with $V=V_1\cup V_2$ and $E=E_1\cup E_2\cup(V_1\diamond V_2)$, where $V_1\diamond V_2=\big\{\{v_1,v_2\} : v_1\in V_1,v_2\in V_2\big\}$ is "unordered" $V_1\times V_2$.
3. If $\chi_{G_1}(t)=\sum\limits_k a_k(t)_k$ and $\chi_{G_2}(t)=\sum\limits_k b_k(t)_k$, then $$\chi_{G_1\diamond G_2}(t)=\sum_k c_k(t)_k,\qquad c_k=\sum_j a_j b_{k-j}.$$ This can be seen from the interpretation of $a_k,b_k,c_k$ given in 1.
4. Now $K_{n,m}=\overline{K}_n\diamond\overline{K}_m$ where $\overline{K}_n$ is the graph with $n$ vertices and no edges. As $\chi_{\overline{K}_n}(t)=t^n$, we need expressions connecting $t^n$ and $(t)_n$; this is where [Stirling numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number) appear. The outcome is $$\chi_{K_{n,m}}(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{m}\begin{Bmatrix}m\\k\end{Bmatrix}(t)_k(t-k)^n.$$

Here is an [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/676754) to check the formula.